# Xcode EXC_BAD_ACCESS debug - Hanging on Loading Screen

Tags: ios, xcode

So, I just came back into Xcode after successfully creating and submitting an app to the iTunes app store.  I came back to do some small edits (it's a quote app, and I added some quotes) and now I'm getting this error...

Foundation -[NSLocalizableString length];

> 0x5dd181 <+6>:  calll  0x5dd186                  ; <+11>
>   Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7daffc)

I've included a screenshot.

This error is making the app stick on loading screen while trying to test it in Simulator.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UksOs.png)

Comment: in my case app is working in  `Xcode 6.4` but not in  `Xcode 7`.

Comment: Chirag ~ this could be my issue, but since it's been upgraded I can't test.